# Importing a table from Access into SQL and removing the carriage returns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm importing a table from Access that has an address field the address field contains carriage returns, these remain when I have imported them into SQL, can I run a SQL script to remove them? Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace Carriage Returns (char(13)) with a single space:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = Replace(MyColumn, CHAR(13), ' ')
```

If you have Carriage Return + LineFeeds:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = Replace(MyColumn, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to replace newline with empty space:

```
replace ( replace(TextValue, char(10),' '), char(13), ' ')
```